# Find the smallest sum of the squares of two measurements taken at least 5 min apart

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem in Python3. I know how to find min1 and min2, but I cannot guess how to search 5 elements in a single pass.

#### Problem Statement

The input program serves measurements performed by a device at intervals of *1* minute. All data are in natural numbers not exceeding *1000*.  **The problem is to find the smallest sum of the squares of two measurements performed at intervals not less than 5 minutes apart.** The first line will contain one natural number -- the number of measurements *N*. It is guaranteed that  *5 < N <= 10000*. Each of the following *N* lines contains one natural number -- the result of the next measurement.

Your program should output a single number, the lowest sum of the squares of two measurements performed at intervals not less than 5 minutes apart.

Sample input:
9
12
45
**5**
4
21
20
10
**12**
26

Expected output: 169

Answer (score 0):

I like this question. Fun brain-teaser. :)

I noticed your sample input was all integers in `range(1, 100)` with some repetition, so I generated sample lists like so:

```
>>> import random                                                           
>>> sample_list = [random.choice(range(1, 100)) for i in range(10)]         
>>> sample_list                                                             
[74, 68, 57, 18, 36, 8, 89, 73, 77, 80]
```

According to the problem statement, these numbers represent data measured at one-minute intervals, and one of our constraints is that our result must represent data gathered at least five minutes apart. Ultimately, that means the indices of the data in the original list must differ by at least five. In other words, for any two inputs `v1` and `v2`:

```
abs(sample_list.index(v1) - sample_list.index(v2)) >= 5
```

must be true. We also know that we're searching for the smallest sum, so it will be helpful to look at the smallest numbers first.

Thus, I started by mapping the values in the sample_list to the indices where they occur, then sorting them:

```
>>> occurrences = {}                                                        
>>> for index, value in enumerate(sample_list):                             
...   try:                                                                          
...     occurrences[value].append(index)                                        
...   except KeyError:                                                      
...     occurrences[value] = [index]                                        
...                                                                         
>>> occurrences                                                             
{80: [9], 18: [3], 68: [1], 73: [7], 89: [6], 8: [5], 57: [2], 74: [0], 77: [8], 36: [4]}
>>> sorted_occurrences = sorted(occurrences)
>>> sorted_occurrences
[8, 18, 36, 57, 68, 73, 74, 77, 80, 89]
```

After a whole lot of trial and error, here's what I finally came up with in function form (including some of the earlier-discussed pieces):

```
def smallest_sum_of_squares_five_apart(sample):
    occurrences = {}
    for index, value in enumerate(sample):
        try:
            occurrences[value].append(index)
        except KeyError:
            occurrences[value] = [index]
    sorted_occurrences = sorted(occurrences)
    least_sum = 0
    for index, v1 in enumerate(sorted_occurrences):
        if least_sum and v1**2 > least_sum:
            return least_sum
        for v2 in sorted_occurrences[:index+1]:
            if (abs(max(occurrences[v1]) - min(occurrences[v2])) >= 5 or
                    abs(max(occurrences[v2]) - min(occurrences[v1])) >= 5):
                print('Found candidates:', str((v1, v2)))
                sum_of_squares = v1**2 + v2**2
                if not least_sum or sum_of_squares < least_sum:
                    least_sum = sum_of_squares
    return least_sum
```

The idea here is to:

- Start by looking at the smallest values first.
- Compare them one by one with all the values smaller, up to themselves.
- Check each against our criteria. Notice we do this by checking the extremes of each, where these two numbers occur the farthest away from one another in the original sample.
- Break out when checking becomes pointless.

Unfortunately, it is not sufficient to find the first one. Depending how the list is constructed, it will not always find the smallest pair first this way. In fact, it does not for your own sample input. However, once `v1**2` (the square of the larger value) is larger than the sum, we know since all numbers are natural numbers it is pointless to continue looking.

I have included a full runnable implementation of this below. It takes a command line argument (default 10) indicating the number of items you want in the randomly generated sample. It will print the randomly generated sample as well as all candidate pairs it checked, and finally the sum itself. I have checked this on 10-sized inputs several times and it seems to be working in general. However, feedback is welcome if it is not correct. Note also you can uncomment your sample list from the question to see how it works (and that it gets the right answer) for it.

```
import random
import sys

def smallest_sum_of_squares_five_apart(sample):
    occurrences = {}
    for index, value in enumerate(sample):
        try:
            occurrences[value].append(index)
        except KeyError:
            occurrences[value] = [index]
    sorted_occurrences = sorted(occurrences)
    least_sum = 0
    for index, v1 in enumerate(sorted_occurrences):
        if least_sum and v1**2 > least_sum:
            return least_sum
        for v2 in sorted_occurrences[:index+1]:
            if (abs(max(occurrences[v1]) - min(occurrences[v2])) >= 5 or
                    abs(max(occurrences[v2]) - min(occurrences[v1])) >= 5):
                print('Found candidates:', str((v1, v2)))
                sum_of_squares = v1**2 + v2**2
                if not least_sum or sum_of_squares < least_sum:
                    least_sum = sum_of_squares
    return least_sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        r = int(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        r = 10
    sample_list = [random.choice(range(1, 100)) for i in range(r)]
    #sample_list = [9, 12, 45, 5, 4, 21, 20, 10, 12, 26]
    print(sample_list)
    print(smallest_sum_of_squares_five_apart(sample_list))
```

Comment: It's always handy to figure out the time complexity of an algorithm. Yours is O(N^2) which is undesirable and should motivate a search for either a better algorithm or a solid reason why it must be O(N^2).

Comment: @Richard There's also more than one way to measure complexity. Mine is O(N^2) in _the worst case_ but has a breakout condition that prevents it from reaching that most of the time. In the average case it is doing far less work, checking only a handful of elements. Granted neither estimate includes the time for sorting/other pre-work. Anyway always glad to see alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import queue

inp = [9,12,45,5,4,21,20,10,12,26]

q        = queue.Queue()                         #Make a new queue
smallest = False                                 #No smallest number, yet
best     = False                                 #No best sum of squares, yet
for x in inp:
  q.put(x)                                       #Place current element on queue
  #If there's an item from more than five minutes ago, consider it
  if q.qsize()>5:
    temp = q.get()    #Pop oldest item from queue into temporary variable
    if not smallest:  #If this is the first item more than 5 minutes old
      smallest = temp #it is the smallest item by default
    else:             #otherwise...
      smallest = min(temp,smallest) #only store it if it is the smallest yet

    #If we have no best sum of squares or the current item produces one, then
    #save it as the best
    if (not best) or (x*x+smallest*smallest<best):
      best = x*x+smallest*smallest

print(best)
```

The idea is to walk through the queue keeping track of the smallest element we have seen yet which is older than five minutes and comparing it against the newest element keeping track of the smallest sum of squares as we go.

I think you'll find the answer to be pretty intuitive if you think about it.

The algorithm operates in O(N) time.